# python signals - execute callback in separate thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, signals, scrapy, twisted

Some context...

I've got a thread that holds my Rabbit consumer class `RabbitClient` say.

When the client consumes a message from the queue, it feeds it to its `CrawlWorker` - an object that manages the lifecycle of spiders, and catches scraped items.

To publish back to the queue, it needs to connect a "publish" callback to the `CrawlWorker`'s `item_scraped` signal, which it does just fine.

However, this callback executes on the main thread - and not the thread that holds the Rabbit client. Is there a way, to make sure the callback is invoked on the thread that holds the Rabbit client?

Here's a very simple example - I think I've boiled the problem down to its essence:

```
import threading
import logging

from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager
from twisted.internet import reactor

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')

SIGNAL = object()


def func():
    message = 'Message from {0}!'.format(threading.currentThread().name)

    signals.send_catch_log(SIGNAL, message=message)


class ReceiverThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, signals):
        self.signals = signals
        self.signals.connect(self.receive, signal=SIGNAL)

        super(ReceiverThread, self).__init__(group=None, target=None,
                                             name='ReceiverThread', verbose=False)

    def receive(self, message):
        logging.info('Received message: {0}'.format(message))

    def run(self):
        # func()
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signals = SignalManager()

    thread = ReceiverThread(signals)
    thread.start()

    func()

    reactor.run()
```

If you run this, you get the message:

```
(MainThread) Received message: Message from MainThread!
```

Commenting in the `func()` call in `run()`, and commenting out the `func()` call in `__main__` will give:

```
(ReceiverThread) Received message: Message from ReceiverThread!
```

I'm not that experienced in threaded programming, so these results are probably expected for most people reading this, but is there a way to get:

```
(ReceiverThread) Received message: Message from MainThread!
```

Comment: If you were running Twisted in the other thread, you could do `reactor.callFromThread(...)`.

Comment: I'm doing that in `RabbitDaemon` to feed the worker `crawl_messages`: `reactor.callFromThread(self.crawl_worker.handle_message, crawl_message, delivery_tag)`, which works. But to get the scraped item, there's a line in the `run()` method:   `self.crawl_worker.connect_to_scrape(self.publish)`. Works fine too, but `self.publish` is invoked in `MainThread`, not `RabbitDaemon`'s. Is there a way for `reactor.callFromThread` to specify the thread context for `self.publish`?

Comment: I'd like to not have the callback invoked in the reactor thread, but in the  `RabbitDaemon` thread.

Comment: No.  `reactor.callFromThread` calls the function in the thread the reactor is running in.  It has to work this way.  You can't call a function in an arbitrary thread (well, not on most systems, and where you can it's pretty dangerous).  You need cooperate from that thread.  Does `RabbitDaemon` cooperate in this way?  Twisted does - by providing `reactor.callFromThread`.  If `RabbitDaemon` provides an equivalent API, that's your solution.  If it doesn't, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems pretty clear to me that I need to provide an equivalent API, if it's worth it to have the Rabbit client on its own thread.